# Graph with the number of events per hour?

Tags: time, graph

I've got a list of Unix time stamps that looks like this:

```
1410576653
1410554469
1410527323
1410462212
1410431156
1410403429
1410403373
1410403258
1410402648
1410381795
1410293563
1410293330
1410292982
1410292718
1410276140
1410260911
1410233396
1410232755
1410229962
1410228512
1410222924
1410222655
1410221546
1410219208
1410218477
```

These were collected every time a certain event happened on my application.
I've got about 1100 of these within a timespan of about 4 years.

I want to find out what hours of the day the events happen most (or don't happen) on.

What would be the best way to create a graph with the number of events that happened per hour?

Comment: how you're planning to build graph, in excel or using any programming language? please specify.

Comment: I didn't specify this because I'm looking for what you think would be the best way to do this.
If you think this is better to do with Excel than a programming language, then Excel.

Comment: "best" will become an open ended discussion topic, which is not the purpose of SO. Do some googling find the "best" suitable solution try it yourself, if you face any difficulties post it here. Please do read the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask